# Results of tbb::parallel_reduce and std::accumulate differ

Tags: c++, c++11, reduce, tbb

I am learning [Intel's TBB library](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org). When summing all values in a `std::vector` the result of `tbb::parallel_reduce` differs from `std::accumulate` in the case of more than 16.777.220 elements in the vector (errors experienced at 16.777.320 elements). Here is my minimum-working-example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>
#include "tbb/tbb.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int count = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() * 0.0079 - 187800; // - 187900 works

    std::vector<float> heights(size);
    std::fill(heights.begin(), heights.end(), 1.0f);

    float ssum = std::accumulate(heights.begin(), heights.end(), 0);
    float psum = tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<float>::iterator>(heights.begin(), heights.end()), 0,
                                      [](tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<float>::iterator> const& range, float init) {
                                          return std::accumulate(range.begin(), range.end(), init);
                                      }, std::plus<float>()
                                      );

    std::cout << std::endl << " Heights serial sum: " << ssum << "   parallel sum: " << psum;
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs on my OSX 10.10.3 with XCode 6.3.1 and tbb stable 4.3-20141023 (poured from [Brew](http://brew.sh)):

```
Heights serial sum: 1.67772e+07   parallel sum: 1.67773e+07
```

**Why is that? Should I report an error to TBB developers?**

---

Additional testing, applying your answers:

```
 correct value is: 1949700403
 cause we add 1.0f to zero 1949700403 times

 using (int) init values:
 Runtime: 17.407 sec. Heights serial   sum: 16777216.000, wrong
 Runtime:  8.482 sec. Heights parallel sum: 131127368.000, wrong

 using (float) init values:
 Runtime: 12.594 sec. Heights serial   sum: 16777216.000, wrong
 Runtime:  5.044 sec. Heights parallel sum: 303073632.000, wrong

 using (double) initial values:
 Runtime: 13.671 sec. Heights serial   sum: 1949700352.000, wrong
 Runtime:  5.343 sec. Heights parallel sum: 263690016.000, wrong

 using (double) initial values and tbb::parallel_deterministic_reduce:
 Runtime: 13.463 sec. Heights serial   sum: 1949700352.000, wrong
 Runtime: 99.031 sec. Heights parallel sum: 1949700352.000, wrong >>> almost 10x slower !
```

***Why do all reduce calls produce the wrong sum? Is `(double)` not sufficient?***
Here is my testing code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <limits>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "tbb/tbb.h"
    #include <cmath>

    class StopWatch {
    private:
        double elapsedTime;
        timeval startTime, endTime;
    public:
        StopWatch () : elapsedTime(0) {}
        void startTimer() {
            elapsedTime = 0;
            gettimeofday(&startTime, 0);
        }
        void stopNprintTimer() {
            gettimeofday(&endTime, 0);
            elapsedTime = (endTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec) * 1000.0;             // compute sec to ms
            elapsedTime += (endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec) / 1000.0;          // compute us to ms and add
            std::cout << " Runtime: " << std::right << std::setw(6) << elapsedTime / 1000 << " sec.";             // show in sec
        }
    };

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        StopWatch watch;
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << "" << std::endl;
        size_t count = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() * 0.9079;

        std::vector<float> heights(count);
        std::cout << " Vector size: " << count << std::endl;
        std::fill(heights.begin(), heights.end(), 1.0f);

        watch.startTimer();
        float ssum = std::accumulate(heights.begin(), heights.end(), 0.0); // change type of initial value here
        watch.stopNprintTimer();
        std::cout << " Heights serial   sum: " << std::right << std::setw(8) << ssum << std::endl;

        watch.startTimer();
        float psum = tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<float>::iterator>(heights.begin(), heights.end()), 0.0, // change type of initial value here
                                          [](tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<float>::iterator> const& range, float init) {
                                              return std::accumulate(range.begin(), range.end(), init);
                                          }, std::plus<float>()
                                          );
        watch.stopNprintTimer();
        std::cout << " Heights parallel sum: " << std::right << std::setw(8) << psum << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

---

***Answer to my last question:*** they all produce wrong results because they are not made for integer addition with large numbers. Switching to int solves that:

```
[...]
std::vector<int> heights(count);
std::cout << " Vector size: " << count << std::endl;
std::fill(heights.begin(), heights.end(), 1);

watch.startTimer();
int ssum = std::accumulate(heights.begin(), heights.end(), (int)0);
watch.stopNprintTimer();
std::cout << " Heights serial   sum: " << std::right << std::setw(8) << ssum << std::endl;

watch.startTimer();
int psum = tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<int>::iterator>(heights.begin(), heights.end()), (int)0,
                                  [](tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<int>::iterator> const& range, int init) {
                                      return std::accumulate(range.begin(), range.end(), init);
                                  }, std::plus<int>()
                                  );
watch.stopNprintTimer();
std::cout << " Heights parallel sum: " << std::right << std::setw(8) << psum << std::endl;
[...]
```

results in:

```
Vector size: 1949700403
Runtime: 13.041 sec. Heights serial   sum: 1949700403, correct
Runtime:  4.728 sec. Heights parallel sum: 1949700403, correct and almost 4x faster
```

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not real numbers arithmetic. If you change the order of operations, you will likely get different round-off errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your call to `std::accumulate` is doing integer addition, then transforming the result to `float` at the end of the calculation. In order to accumulate over floating point numbers, the accumulator should be a `float`<sup>*</sup>.

```
float ssum = std::accumulate(heights.begin(), heights.end(), 0.0f);
                                                             ^^^^
```

---

<sup>* Or any other type that can accumulate `float` correctly.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. As the std::accumulate template syntax shows, I used an int here and only was lucky, that I filled my vector with 1.0f which is 1 when converted to int. When using a float value the result is still incorrect. But this time due to the inaccuracy of the float datatype in higher number regions.

Answer (score 3):

This may fix this particular problem for you:

> Your call to std::accumulate is doing integer addition, then transforming the result to float at the end of the calculation.

BUT floating point addition is NOT an associative operation:

- With accumulate: (...((s+a1)+a2)+...)+an
- With parralel_reduce: any parenthesis permutation possible.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the float accuracy problem here and the link to the great document (upvoted).

Answer (score 3):

To other correct answers for the 'why?' part, I'd also add that TBB provides [`parallel_deterministic_reduce`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_deterministic_reduce_func.htm) which guarantees reproducible results between two and more runs on the same data (but it still can differ with std::accumulate). See [the blog](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/05/11/deterministic-reduction-a-new-community-preview-feature-in-intel-threading-building-blocks) describing the issue and the deterministic algorithm.

Thus regarding 'Should I report an error to TBB developers?' part, the answer is obviously no (unless you find something insufficient on the TBB side).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately it needs more time on my 4 thread intel i7 than the serial std::accumulate() with double type for the initial value.

Comment: Reading the link carefully I understand now, that `tbb::parallel_deterministic_reduce` does not produce correct results, but at least repeated incorrect result, meaning each run will produce the same error. May I cite: _It’s important to note that a repeatable result obtained with parallel_deterministic_reduce may still be different from that obtained via serial execution. [..] Also, the algorithm is not targeted to improve the accuracy of calculations._

Comment: It is not an error. Or the same can be said about std::accumulate

Comment: For small numbers parallelism might not be worth. But it is also hard to benchmark TBB right since creation of threads is usually on the way while in real applications it is not.

Comment: You want to have a much bigger block size than the default of `1uz`.